# How to create slot-machine metaphor in SwiftUI Picker?

Tags: swiftui

Is it possible to create a slot machine with swiftUI to show two sets of values?

[image: Example picture]

Comment: If you just want to show two date values like in the image, you can just use a `DatePicker`. Not sure about if its possible to do that currently with a regular `Picker`

Comment: DatePicker would be good solution, but as I understood there are only two options: 1. Displays day, month, and year 
2. Displays hour and minute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In UIKit, `UIPickerView` provides the option to have multiple components in your picker view. SwiftUI's `Picker` does not. However, you can use more than one `Picker` in an `HStack` instead. The perspective may look slightly different than a `UIPickerView` with multiple components in some instances, but to me it looks perfectly acceptable.

Here's an example of a slot machine with 4 pickers side by side and a button that "spins" the slot-machine when tapped (note that I disabled user interaction on the pickers so they can only be spun using the button):

```swift
enum Suit: String {
    case heart, club, spade, diamond

    var displayImage: Image {
        return Image(systemName: "suit.\(self.rawValue).fill")
    }
}
```

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var suits: [Suit] = [.heart, .club, .spade, .diamond]
    @State private var selectedSuits: [Suit] = [.heart, .heart, .heart, .heart]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(0..<self.selectedSuits.count, id: \.self) { index in
                    Picker("Suits", selection: self.$selectedSuits[index]) {
                        ForEach(self.suits, id: \.self) { suit in
                            suit.displayImage
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .clipped()
                    .disabled(true)
                }
            }
            Button(action: self.spin) {
                Text("Spin")
            }
        }
    }

    private func spin() {
        self.selectedSuits = self.selectedSuits.map { _ in
            self.suits.randomElement()!
        }
    }
}
```

This is just an example, and could no doubt be improved, but it's a decent starting point.

Keep in mind that this code does throw a warning in Xcode Beta 5 -

> 'subscript(_:)' is deprecated: See Release Notes for migration path.

I haven't had a chance to look into this, but the example still works and should help you with what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: That is exactly what I need. Thanks!